# How to check if a TypedPipe or a ValuePipe are empty in Scalding?

Tags: scalding

In Scalding, suppose you have a `TypedPipe[Long]` or `ValuePipe[Long]`. How would you go about checking whether they are empty in the most elegant/efficient way?

Currently testing the following:

```
val isTPEmpty: Boolean = typePipe.equals(TypedPipe.empty)
val isVPEmpty: Boolean = valuePipe.equals(EmptyValue)
```

Or, to make it more generic:

```
def isTypedPipeEmpty[A](typedPipe: TypedPipe[A]): Boolean = {
  val emptyTP: TypedPipe[A] = TypedPipe.empty
  typedPipe.equals(emptyTP)
}
```

UPDATE: this doesn't work (will return `false` for an empty `TypedPipe`). Appreciate any inputs.

Comment: You could use a join, or create a TypedPipe containing an Option of value. How do you intend to use the resulting boolean?

Comment: I needed this for a simple if-else check. If the TypedPipe were empty, then I could avoid a whole bunch of MapReduce stages. I got another advice saying that this "requirement" is in itself problematic/wasteful since a TypedPipe is parallelized. And currently I *am* able to avoid this, I'm thinking of writing this here as the solution.

Comment: Take a look at Execution - perhaps the condition can be used to trigger different execution. Best documentation appears to be here: https://github.com/twitter/scalding/releases/tag/0.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking to several people on this, there is no straight solution simply because a TypedPipe is distributed, and checking whether it is empty is "expensive", therefore one should avoid this as much as possible.

If you absolutely have no choice, what worked for me was something "ugly" as creating a temporary empty TypedPipe, then calling `mapWithValue` on my ValuePipe, and if it is empty do X, otherwise do Y. Something like:

```
TypedPipe.from(List()).mapWithValue(valuePipe) { case (temp, valuePipe) => if (valuePipe.isEmpty) doX else doY }
```

But again, cumbersome.